# HP Nonstop Tandem T4SQLMX driver double precision issue

Tags: precision, hp-nonstop, tandem, sqlmx

I use T4SQLMX type 4 jdbc driver to read a double precision field from a SQL/MX table. The Actual value is **29963.26**, however, the value read using the jdbc driver seems to be **29963.260000000002**. This seems to be an issue even if I read it as resultset.getString() or resultset.getBigDecimal() because the driver always returns 29963.260000000002.

Similarly, value **99.76** is returned as **99.759999999999**. 
We use CAIL to view the actual value **99.76** from the SQL/MX table, and SQL-Squirrel client and web-app uses sqlmx jdbc driver where we see the value as **99.759999999999**

Has anyone faced this or similar issue and have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the double inside of a BigDecimal, then used setscale to 2 digits

`BigDecimal.valueOf((resultset.getDouble(<column name here))).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));`